# SQL Server unable to upload excel file

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008

[image: the last step]

I try to create a new table by uploading an Excel file, but it is stuck on the last step of SQL Server Import and Export Wizard; the `openrowset` function works

Comment: Go back to step 1½ and set each of the field types and subtypes correctly. The Import and Export wizard make a large number of assumptions based upon a small 'look-ahead' of rows. You can also change this 'look-ahead' to look at more rows in the registry. In short, there are a lot of potential reasons why the import didn't work but you have not provided anywhere near enough information to provide a resolution beyond wide generalities.

Comment: I followed the instructions and SQL server reported nothing,I did the same upload every day and nothing went wrong, yesterday I tried to use openrowset function to upload files and maybe I've changed same default settings

Answer (score 0):

While importing excel file in sql server you would have got excel, Select microsoft Excel 97-2003 format if you are using latest verion of excel Or else it's better you export it to access database and upload it.